# Building a React mega menu

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, megamenu

I'm building an app in React with a Django backend.  My goal is to use no jQuery at all.  I'd like to have a responsive "mega menu," but most code examples I see are built with jQuery.

Does anyone have a tip on making a React responsive mega menu?

Comment: Could you show a code snippet of what you have tried?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? It would be good to see your solution if you did or some more information about what you want to achieve/your current code so we can help.